# Validator in ControlsFX Wizard last page

Tags: java, controlsfx

Is there any way of adding a Validator to the last page in ControlsFX Wizards?

I am currently using the following on the last page :

```
    public void onEnteringPage(Wizard wizard) {
            wizard.getValidationSupport().registerValidator(cb, 
            Validator.createEmptyValidator("The instance field is mandatory"));
```

But since this is the last page I am still able to click finish when the cb(choice box) is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I think this is due to a bug in version 8.40.9 of ControlsFX where they forgot to check the FINISH Button against the invalid property, too.

Look here in the Issue [Issue 521](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-requests/521/updated-code-to-allow-a-wizardpane-to/diff#Lcontrolsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/dialog/Wizard.javaT633) at line 633. They have added the necessary call. Just wait for the next update, when the issue will be merged.

For a quick and dirty workaround just add another pane to your wizard. With a text "Finished" for example, because on the "next" buttons the validation works.